How to create Map of Map in Java from a List
I have a List of Root object List rootList;
class Root {
    int level;
    String path;
    String siteId;
    String siteName;
}

In this object, level & path are not unique. For example Level can be 2 and path can be 1.2.3, 1.3.4, 1.5.6... etc and the site can be multiple for a single path.
I want to convert rootList to Map<level, Map<Path, List<Root>> sites;Now for each level and path, I can bring the List of Sites.
If I use, Stream Foreach, I am not able to get the List and this approach is not at all working. Please kindly help me in bringing this structure.
rootList.stream().forEach(root -> sites.put(root.getLevel(), root.getPath())).;


Please rephrase the question. Its not clear what is required. How is converting rootList to Map of Map making it unique ?

Hi  @Codemaster, I have updated the question. Could you please kindly let me know if it needs additional changes?

You can use Collectors to do this:
First a groupingBy collector to create the top level map, which uses another groupingBy collector to create each sub map, with the values populated by a toList.
package com.example.so;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public class Eg {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Root> roots = List.of(
                new Root(1, "A", "B"),
                new Root(1, "A", "C"),
                new Root(2, "A", "B"),
                new Root(2, "A", "C"),
                new Root(1, "Z", "B"),
                new Root(1, "Z", "C"),
                new Root(2, "Z", "B"),
                new Root(2, "Z", "C")
        );
        Map<Integer, Map<String,List<Root>>> maps = roots.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Root::level,
                Collectors.groupingBy(Root::path, Collectors.toList())
        ));
        System.out.println(maps);
    }

}

record Root(int level, String path, String siteId) {
}

Which produces the structure:
 {
 1=
   {
   A=[Root[level=1, path=A, siteId=B], Root[level=1, path=A, siteId=C]],
   Z=[Root[level=1, path=Z, siteId=B], Root[level=1, path=Z, siteId=C]]
   },
 2=
   {
   A=[Root[level=2, path=A, siteId=B], Root[level=2, path=A, siteId=C]],
   Z=[Root[level=2, path=Z, siteId=B], Root[level=2, path=Z, siteId=C]]
   }
 }


Hi @tgdavies, The second groupingBy is showing one error
The method groupingBy(Function<? super T,? extends K>, Collector<? super T,A,D>) in the type Collectors is not applicable for the arguments (Root::path, Collector<Object,capture#1-of ?,List>)

Which JDK are you using? The code above is fine on JDK 21.

I am using Older Version Java 8, My Bad

With the following code it is working in Java 8.
roots.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Root::getLevel,
Collectors.groupingBy(Root::getPath)));

You can use collectors and streams logic as below:


Map<Integer, Map<String, List<Root>>> sites = rootList.stream()
                .collect(
                        HashMap::new,
                        (map, root) -> map.computeIfAbsent(root.getLevel(), k -> new HashMap<>())
                                .merge(root.getPath(), new ArrayList<>(List.of(root)), (l1, l2) -> {l1.addAll(l2); return l1;}), // Accumulator
                        HashMap::putAll
                );




Hi @Siddhartha Sengupta, I am using Java 8 right now. The method List.of is not available in java 8 and is giving error

Change List.of() to Arrays.aslist() and it will be compliant with Java 8.  The latter was introduced in Java 1.2

As an alternative to Streams, you can also use the enhancements to the Map interface, also available in Java 8.
Map.computeIfAbsent - creates the value for the supplied key if absent.  Then, always returns that value for subsequent operations.  In this case, another computeIfAbsent invocation.
Map<Integer, Map<String, List<Root>>> maps = new HashMap<>();
 for (Root root : roots) {
     maps.computeIfAbsent(root.getLevel(), k -> new HashMap<>())
             .computeIfAbsent(root.getPath(), k -> new ArrayList<>())
             .add(root);
 }

